# urlrewriter.net

Tags: asp.net, regex, iis, url-rewriting

I have a question concerning urlrewiter. I want to rewrite the following url like this:

```
<rewrite url="~/sportswear/browse-by-category/(\d+)/(.+)/(\d+)" to="~/Browse.aspx?cid=9&amp;type=category&amp;mid=$1&amp;p=$2" />
```

This does work but my get variable p cannot be read. However when i write 'shoes' which is the categoryname instead of (.+) it works perfectly. Does anyone know what seems to be the problem?

Thanks for your time.

Kind regards,
Mark

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you should start learning to make your groups non capture:

```
<rewrite url="~/sportswear/browse-by-category/(\d+)/(?:.+)/(\d+)" to="~/Browse.aspx?cid=9&amp;type=category&amp;mid=$1&amp;p=$2" />
```

Basically, just use (?:) instead of () if you don't want to capture it.
Additionally, there was no need to group that .+, no?

```
<rewrite url="~/sportswear/browse-by-category/(\d+)/.+/(\d+)" to="~/Browse.aspx?cid=9&amp;type=category&amp;mid=$1&amp;p=$2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Oooow sorry guys, i figured it out already, i had to replace $2 with $3 since that was the regex array number. Thanks anyways! :)